# Why am I getting last line first when processing just created file?

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script which parses an XML file and creates a file with the extracted data (extracted file).

In the same batch script I then use the extracted file to create a file with SQL commands (sql file).

When I start to create the SQL file I get the last record (line) from the extracted file first and the statement is created correctly.

How do stop from getting the last record first at :buildsql?

```
@echo off
echo Beginning parsing of XML files for pagecount and docid extraction.
echo Processing...
SET /A counter = 0
FOR /F %%i IN (CDIZeroPage.TXT) DO (
  IF EXIST %%i (
    FOR /F "tokens=12 delims==" %%h IN (%%i) DO (CALL :pagestring %%h)
    FOR /F "tokens=8 delims==" %%g IN (%%i) DO (CALL :docidstring %%g)
  )
)
goto buildsql

:pagestring
  echo %1 >> C:\Richtemp\PagesandDocs.txt
  CALL set page=%1
goto :eof

:docidstring
  echo %1 >> C:\Richtemp\PagesandDocs.txt
  CALL SET docid=%1
  SET /A counter+=1
goto :eof

:buildsql
echo End extracting pagecount and docid.
echo Number of files processed %counter%
echo       
echo Begin building SQL
echo Processing...
SET /A counter=0
SET /A countbytwo=0
FOR /F %%i IN (PagesandDocs.txt) DO (
  CALL :subroutine %%i
  SET /A counter+=1
)
goto endofscript

:subroutine
  SET /A countbytwo+=1
  IF %countbytwo%==1 (
    FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%G IN ('ECHO %1') DO (SET page=%%~G)
    echo Update documents set pagecount = %page% >> C:\Richtemp\Update.txt
  )
  IF %countbytwo%==2 (
    FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%G IN ('ECHO %1') DO (SET docid=%%~G)
    echo where uniqueid = %docid% ^; >> C:\Richtemp\Update.txt
    SET /A countbytwo=0
  )
goto :eof

:endofscript
  SET /A counter/=2
  echo End building sql, number of scripts built %counter%

:eof
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
:docidstring
  echo %1 >> C:\Richtemp\PagesandDocs.txt
  CALL SET docid=%1
  SET /A counter+=1
goto :eof
```

in the code above, you set docid. At the end of your first phase of processing, it will store last line in `docid`. Then you call `buildsql`, and problem is here:

```
 IF %countbytwo%==2 (
    FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%G IN ('ECHO %1') DO (SET docid=%%~G)
    echo where uniqueid = %docid% ^; >> C:\Richtemp\Update.txt
    SET /A countbytwo=0
  )
```

You would think that `echo` will use `docid` you just set, unfortunately it's not. It gets substituted **earlier on expansion**  with old value of `docid`... which on first call .refers to your last line. Exactly same error happens with `page` variable

You probably could use delayed expansion to get round this, but your code looks overly complicated. What exactly you want to achieve? If the intention was to extract items from positions 12,8 on a line and build a query expression like this:

```
Update documents set pagecount = #12 where where uniqueid = #8;
```

it will not work as intended because you first offload all your #12, and then #8 into file.

Maybe this would work for you?

```
    setlocal
    FOR /F %%i IN (CDIZeroPage.TXT) DO (
    FOR /F "tokens=8-12 delims==" %%j IN (%%i) do (
       ECHO Update documents set pagecount = %%n where where uniqueid = %%j ^; >>update.txt
       SET /A counter+=1
    )
)
echo End building sql, number of scripts built %counter%
```

Comment: Yes, it was overly complicated.  I slimmed it down and wrote both files at once which 'fixed' my problem.  I just wasn't able to determine why the last record was written first in this version.  Thank you for the explanation, it will help me in writing scripts.